# 2010 - displayNames from Active Directory not staying consistent

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, profile-sync, display-name

We are having a problem in which the "Name" portion of some people's profiles are being updated on the periodic sync wiping out the proper displayName which should just be their first and last names and instead replacing it with their account name which is 'domain\username'. I did a full sync yesterday, and just about all the names came in correctly. There was just one that didn't. A double check of active directory showed that the 'Display Name' field was properly filled for all users. A check this morning of the profiles showed that 36 of the over 400 profiles we have now show the improper display name. In active directory, though, the display name field is still fill in properly. What could cause sharepoint to improperly load this field?

Comment: What you are calling display name is the PreferredName field in the SharePoint User Profile (Not First Name Last Name). I have seen cases where having a different NetBIOS name and Forest name would cause this issue.

Comment: I think this is the issue. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a solution other than to manually switch people back. It appears this only happens once to each user. So if we reset their preferredname back to first and last it should stick around I believe.

Comment: Is your NetBIOS name different from the forest name? If so you need to set the NetBIOSDomainNamesEnabled flag on the UPA before performing the import.